# Get NDIS Version(s)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ndis

I know that I could use Windows PowerShell

`Get-netadapter|select Name, ndisversion`

to pipe the results out to a text file, and parse the data from there, but that's sort of hacky. I was wondering if there's a way to get the same info using something more direct? i.e. WMI or a Framework class, etc.? I've Googled, but came up empty-handed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the NetAdapter powershell cmdlets are thin wrappers over WMI objects.  So you can indeed use the `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` namespace directly.

In this case, you'd enumerate instances of `root\standardcimv2\MSFT_NetAdapter` to look at their `Name` and `DriverMajorNdisVersion` fields.

This isn't a complete tutorial on the MI APIs, but here's a pseudocode sketch of the idea:

```
var session = CimSession.Create(. . .);
foreach (var instance in session.EnumerateInstances(@"root\standardcimv2", "MSFT_NetAdapter")) {
    var name = instance.CimInstanceProperties["Name"].Value as string;
    var major = instance.CimInstanceProperties["DriverMajorNdisVersion"].Value as byte;
    WriteLine($"{name}: {major}.{minor}");
}
```

Comment: Excellent!, ty.